# Angular4 and Swagger Client

Tags: angular, swagger-2.0, angular-httpclient

maybe someone can help. I try to use the default service in my component for communicat with REST API to a backend python-Server. I try to used the swagger-codegen generated ng2 Client in angular. The Python server is also generated by swagger. The server is working,

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { RequestMethod, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Response, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import '../rxjs-operators';

import { InlineResponseDefault } from '../model/inlineResponseDefault';

import { BASE_PATH, COLLECTION_FORMATS } from '../variables';
import { Configuration } from '../configuration';
import { CustomQueryEncoderHelper } from '../encoder';


@Injectable()
export class DefaultService {

    protected basePath = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1';
    public defaultHeaders = new Headers();
    public configuration = new Configuration();

    constructor(protected http: Http, @Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string, @Optional() configuration: Configuration) {
        if (basePath) {
            this.basePath = basePath;
        }
        if (configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            this.basePath = basePath || configuration.basePath || this.basePath;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param consumes string[] mime-types
     * @return true: consumes contains 'multipart/form-data', false: otherwise
     */
    private canConsumeForm(consumes: string[]): boolean {
        const form = 'multipart/form-data';
        for (let consume of consumes) {
            if (form === consume) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public isJsonMime(mime: string): boolean {
        const jsonMime: RegExp = new RegExp('^(application\/json|[^;/ \t]+\/[^;/ \t]+[+]json)[ \t]*(;.*)?$', 'i');
        return mime != null && (jsonMime.test(mime) || mime.toLowerCase() === 'application/json-patch+json');
    }

    /**
     * Abort the programm in the project identified by UUID
     * @param UUID The UUID
     */
    public abortProject(UUID: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<{}> {
        return this.abortProjectWithHttpInfo(UUID, extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json() || {};
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * delete a single file at a specified path
     * @param UUID The UUID
     * @param path The path where to upload.
     */
    public deleteFile(UUID: string, path: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<{}> {
        return this.deleteFileWithHttpInfo(UUID, path, extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json() || {};
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Testing the connection
     */
    public ping(extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<string> {
        return this.pingWithHttpInfo(extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json() || {};
                }
            });
    }
```

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DefaultService } from './rest/api/default.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [DefaultService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

I've try to inject the default.service in my contsructor and after it the browser give message ERROR NO PROVIDER FOR HTTP Injection error .....
I'm totally newbie in ng and ts :-( . After it i define a function getPing for a console log the answer of the server.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InlineResponseDefault } from '../app/rest';
import { HttpClient, } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { DefaultService } from './rest/api/default.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';


  constructor(private defaultService: DefaultService, public http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getPing() {
    console.log(this.defaultService.ping);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got `Http` in one place and `HttpClient` in another. I strongly recommend [reading the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http). I'm going to assume you intend to use `HttpClient`, but if you want to use `Http` instead, refer to [this other documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6).

In **default.service.ts** update your constructor to use `HttpClient`:

```
constructor(protected http: HttpClient, ... other params ...)
```

In **app.component.ts**:

- remove the `HttpClient` constructor parameter:

  ```
  constructor(private defaultService: DefaultService) {}
  ```
- update your `getPing()` method to actually call the `ping()` method on default service:

  ```
  console.log(this.defaultService.ping());
  ```

  Without the `()` it's returning a function reference and not invoking the function.
- remove the import for HttpClientModule. You only need that in the app.module.ts file.

Your app.module.ts is fine.

Actually I don't see how that default service will even compile since it seems to be invoking a whole bunch of methods that just ... don't exist.

As I mentiond before, this is for `HttpClient`. If you want to use `Http` you need to use `HttpModule` instead. Refer to the documentation I linked above, but it's recommended you use `HttpClient`.

Comment: Thank you i've fix it. You say a whole bunch of methods are not exist... Which methods? I thought that i can call the function from my swagger client and he pings the server ? Can you maybe recommend a source where i can read more about angular4 and client implementation ?

Comment: @PaddyS Undefined methods like this: `this.abortProjectWithHttpInfo(...)`. The "this" keyword indicates that this is a class method, but `DefaultService` has no method declared called `abortProjectWithHttpInfo`. If this is actually a method in your api, you'd have to call something like `this.http.post("http://example.com/api/abortProjectWithHttpInfo",...)`.

Comment: of the Frozen Thank you for your Help. I post the whole default.service file in the comment below with some text.

Comment: @PaddyS You should create a new question if you have additional problems. StackOverflow follows and question-and-answer model, not a thread-with-many-replies model, so we like to keep one concept (or question/answer) per topic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the app.module.ts you are import the HttpClientModule from *@angular/common/http* and in your service, you are trying to inject the HttpClient from *@angular/http*. Those are different version from the Http client, and the *@angular/common/http* is the latest.

Change your service to:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
//
@Injectable()
export class DefaultService {
  constructor(protected http: HttpClient, @Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string, @Optional() configuration: Configuration) {
```

Answer (score 0):

@Roddy of the Frozen thats my whole default.service.ts. You say if i have this methods i need to call `this.http.post("http://example.com/api/abortProjectWithHttpI‌​nfo",...)` but i thought that if i ping the server i can used ping from my default.service. I'm just realizing that the my angular app in browser is empty. The HTML will not be shown.... thats frustrating.

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { RequestMethod, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Response, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import '../rxjs-operators';

import { InlineResponseDefault } from '../model/inlineResponseDefault';

import { BASE_PATH, COLLECTION_FORMATS } from '../variables';
import { Configuration } from '../configuration';
import { CustomQueryEncoderHelper } from '../encoder';


@Injectable()
export class DefaultService {

    protected basePath = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1';
    public defaultHeaders = new Headers();
    public configuration = new Configuration();

    constructor(protected http: HttpClient, @Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string, @Optional() configuration: Configuration) {
        if (basePath) {
            this.basePath = basePath;
        }
        if (configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            this.basePath = basePath || configuration.basePath || this.basePath;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param consumes string[] mime-types
     * @return true: consumes contains 'multipart/form-data', false: otherwise
     */
    private canConsumeForm(consumes: string[]): boolean {
        const form = 'multipart/form-data';
        for (let consume of consumes) {
            if (form === consume) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public isJsonMime(mime: string): boolean {
        const jsonMime: RegExp = new RegExp('^(application\/json|[^;/ \t]+\/[^;/ \t]+[+]json)[ \t]*(;.*)?$', 'i');
        return mime != null && (jsonMime.test(mime) || mime.toLowerCase() === 'application/json-patch+json');
    }

    /**
     * Abort the programm in the project identified by UUID
     * @param UUID The UUID
     */
    public abortProject(UUID: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<{}> {
        return this.abortProjectWithHttpInfo(UUID, extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json() || {};
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * delete a single file at a specified path
     * @param UUID The UUID
     * @param path The path where to upload.
     */
    public deleteFile(UUID: string, path: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<{}> {
        return this.deleteFileWithHttpInfo(UUID, path, extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json() || {};
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Testing the connection
     */
    public ping(extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<string> {
        return this.pingWithHttpInfo(extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json() || {};
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Run the programm in the project identified by UUID
     * @param UUID The UUID
     */
    public runProject(UUID: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<{}> {
        return this.runProjectWithHttpInfo(UUID, extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json() || {};
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Send a single file to the server
     * @param UUID The UUID
     * @param path The path where to upload.
     * @param file The single file to upload.
     */
    public sendFile(UUID: string, path: string, file: Blob, extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<{}> {
        return this.sendFileWithHttpInfo(UUID, path, file, extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json() || {};
                }
            });
    }


    /**
     * 
     * Abort the programm in the project identified by UUID
     * @param UUID The UUID
     */
    public abortProjectWithHttpInfo(UUID: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        if (UUID === null || UUID === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter UUID was null or undefined when calling abortProject.');
        }

        let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON()); // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6845

        // to determine the Content-Type header
        let consumes: string[] = [
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ];
        let canConsumeForm = this.canConsumeForm(consumes);
        let useForm = false;
        let formParams = new (useForm ? FormData : URLSearchParams as any)() as {
          set(param: string, value: any): void;
        };
        if (UUID !== undefined) {
            formParams.set('UUID', <any>UUID);
        }

        let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            headers: headers,
            body: formParams.toString(),
            withCredentials:this.configuration.withCredentials
        });
        // https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4037
        if (extraHttpRequestParams) {
            requestOptions = (<any>Object).assign(requestOptions, extraHttpRequestParams);
        }

        return this.http.request(`${this.basePath}/abort`, requestOptions);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * delete a single file at a specified path
     * @param UUID The UUID
     * @param path The path where to upload.
     */
    public deleteFileWithHttpInfo(UUID: string, path: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        if (UUID === null || UUID === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter UUID was null or undefined when calling deleteFile.');
        }
        if (path === null || path === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter path was null or undefined when calling deleteFile.');
        }

        let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON()); // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6845

        // to determine the Content-Type header
        let consumes: string[] = [
            'multipart/form-data'
        ];
        let canConsumeForm = this.canConsumeForm(consumes);
        let useForm = false;
        let formParams = new (useForm ? FormData : URLSearchParams as any)() as {
          set(param: string, value: any): void;
        };
        if (UUID !== undefined) {
            formParams.set('UUID', <any>UUID);
        }
        if (path !== undefined) {
            formParams.set('path', <any>path);
        }

        let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Delete,
            headers: headers,
            body: formParams.toString(),
            withCredentials:this.configuration.withCredentials
        });
        // https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4037
        if (extraHttpRequestParams) {
            requestOptions = (<any>Object).assign(requestOptions, extraHttpRequestParams);
        }

        return this.http.request(`${this.basePath}/delete`, requestOptions);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Testing the connection
     */
    public pingWithHttpInfo(extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

        let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON()); // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6845

        let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            headers: headers,
            withCredentials:this.configuration.withCredentials
        });
        // https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4037
        if (extraHttpRequestParams) {
            requestOptions = (<any>Object).assign(requestOptions, extraHttpRequestParams);
        }

        return this.http.request(`${this.basePath}/ping`, requestOptions);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Run the programm in the project identified by UUID
     * @param UUID The UUID
     */
    public runProjectWithHttpInfo(UUID: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        if (UUID === null || UUID === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter UUID was null or undefined when calling runProject.');
        }

        let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON()); // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6845

        // to determine the Content-Type header
        let consumes: string[] = [
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ];
        let canConsumeForm = this.canConsumeForm(consumes);
        let useForm = false;
        let formParams = new (useForm ? FormData : URLSearchParams as any)() as {
          set(param: string, value: any): void;
        };
        if (UUID !== undefined) {
            formParams.set('UUID', <any>UUID);
        }

        let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            headers: headers,
            body: formParams.toString(),
            withCredentials:this.configuration.withCredentials
        });
        // https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4037
        if (extraHttpRequestParams) {
            requestOptions = (<any>Object).assign(requestOptions, extraHttpRequestParams);
        }

        return this.http.request(`${this.basePath}/run`, requestOptions);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Send a single file to the server
     * @param UUID The UUID
     * @param path The path where to upload.
     * @param file The single file to upload.
     */
    public sendFileWithHttpInfo(UUID: string, path: string, file: Blob, extraHttpRequestParams?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        if (UUID === null || UUID === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter UUID was null or undefined when calling sendFile.');
        }
        if (path === null || path === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter path was null or undefined when calling sendFile.');
        }
        if (file === null || file === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Required parameter file was null or undefined when calling sendFile.');
        }

        let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON()); // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6845

        // to determine the Content-Type header
        let consumes: string[] = [
            'multipart/form-data'
        ];
        let canConsumeForm = this.canConsumeForm(consumes);
        let useForm = false;
        useForm = canConsumeForm;
        let formParams = new (useForm ? FormData : URLSearchParams as any)() as {
          set(param: string, value: any): void;
        };
        if (UUID !== undefined) {
            formParams.set('UUID', <any>UUID);
        }
        if (path !== undefined) {
            formParams.set('path', <any>path);
        }
        if (file !== undefined) {
            formParams.set('file', <any>file);
        }

        let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            headers: headers,
            body: formParams.toString(),
            withCredentials:this.configuration.withCredentials
        });
        // https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4037
        if (extraHttpRequestParams) {
            requestOptions = (<any>Object).assign(requestOptions, extraHttpRequestParams);
        }

        return this.http.request(`${this.basePath}/files`, requestOptions);
    }

}
```